# Body Close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebox

I've made a form floating in the middle of the screen

And for that I designed a button to close

But I want be anywhere on the screen with the mouse clicked closed form

my code

```js
  $(".offer-close").click(function () {
         $(".div-fix").fadeOut(500);
     });
```

```html
<div class="div-fix">
<div class="offer-shop">

    <div class="cur-package">
        <div class="offer-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
        <h6>Service</h6>

        <div class="pack-b">

            <div class="pack-price">6500 <div>
            <br>

            <div class="pack-shop"><a href="#" target="blank">Buy</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pack-c">any ...</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

For example, form feedback website : http://cssdeck.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding below script will solve your problem.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".div-fix");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/verhh5uw/2/)**

Comment: @desall Hi, I have few modification in you code please check https://jsfiddle.net/chf7osfs/1/

Comment: @desall Your code not working because `.div-fix` covered whole screen, in other words; there is no target element (like body tag) to close on tap outside of `div-fix`